# Differentiate between 2 users sessions using SharedPreferences Android

Tags: android, session

I am developing a login android app. I am using SharedPreferences class to maintain session. I know that  SharedPreferences class returns the same instance to all the users in the application if the pref file name is same. So, if one user stores his username and password in SharedPreferences class and another user comes in and uses the same filename, can he get access to the previous user's username and password?
How does SharedPrefereces differentiate between two users? How does we maintain different session objects for two users using SharedPreferences class so that they can't interfere in each other data?
Please clarify it...

Comment: What do you mean by 2 different users?  Do you mean 2 different people on the same Android device, so they have switched the effective user via the Android provide controls?

Comment: Suppose if there are 2 Android devices running the same app and both call the Sharedpreferences Class with same file name,would both those devices get the same instance of SharedPreferences class or different one?If both get the same instance on different devices, how will we differentiate one device user to another?

Comment: Each device runs separate instances of your app and its classes.

Comment: Thanx Larry for your time and help..I got it.